# rails 5.2 how to get form-data value in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a simple HTML form and I'm sending some data to my server by using Fetch API and FormData.

I'm sending `role` and `user_id` with their values to the server. In controller when I print `params` I get:

> {"-----------------------------1190833731009709688837505639\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name"=>"\"role\"\r\n\r\nadmin\r\n-----------------------------1190833731009709688837505639\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------1190833731009709688837505639--\r\n", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"updaterole", "id"=>"1"}

How can I access and get `role` and `user_id` value from this?

This is my script on client side:

```
var form = document.querySelector("#roleForm");
var formdata = new FormData(form);

fetch(url, {
    method: "PATCH",
    headers: { 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' },
    body: formdata,
}).then(
    response => response.text() // .json(), etc.
    // same as function(response) {return response.text();}
).then(
    html => {
        console.log(html)
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `params` you are seeing on the server? It seems it got lost when posting your question.

Comment: here u go.. its when i print params in console:

{"-----------------------------1190833731009709688837505639\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name"=>"\"role\"\r\n\r\nadmin\r\n-----------------------------1190833731009709688837505639\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_id\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n-----------------------------1190833731009709688837505639--\r\n", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"updaterole", "id"=>"1"}

Comment: hmmm looks like the body is not right, try to create the formdata object manually (`formdata = new FormData(); data.append('role', selected_role); data.append('user_id', theuserid)`) just to make the content more explicit

Comment: If you do not have file upload try to send json payload to server. But you need to change content type to `application/json`.

Comment: yes thanks to all for help... i just removed (headers: { 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' }) in fetch request and now my problem is fixed

Comment: @ultra2mh, could you please post the solution, to not leave the question unanswered

Comment: ok i added the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case, that it is alredy mentioned in comments, we have incorrect body.
i solved it by removing  `headers: { 'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data' },` form fetch request.. looks like we dont need  add Content-Type to header. anyway my issue solved by this .

Comment: Worked for me, thanks.